# How to get Array data wihile ng-change function in ng repeat for every iteration

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http, jsonFilter) {

  $scope.loadcat = function() {
    $http.get("cat_load.php")

      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.CategoryArray = data;
      });
  }

  $scope.GetProduct = function(categoryid, index) {
    $http.post("product_load.php", {
        'cat_id': categoryid
      })

      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.ProductsArray[index] = data;
      });
  }

  $scope.GetSubCategory = function(categoryid, productname) {
    $http.post("subcat_load.php", {
        'cat_id': categoryid,
        'productname': productname
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.subcatids = data;
      });
  }


  /**********to add remove row start here **********/

  $scope.remove_Row = function(name) {
    var index = -1;
    var comArr = eval($scope.data);
    for (var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++) {
      if (comArr[i].name == name) {

        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (index == -1) {
      //alert( "Something gone wrong" );
    }
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
  };

  // dynamic row creation 
  $scope.data = [{}];
  $scope.addFormField = function() {
    //alert($scope.data);
    $scope.data.push({});
  }

  /**********to add remove row End here **********/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="no-skin" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="2%">Sr.No</th>
        <th width="10%">Category Type <span class="error">*</span></th>
        <th width="10%">Product <span class="error">*</span></th>
        <th width="10%">Sub Category</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="cap in data">

      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>

      <td data-title="'Category Type'" sortable="Category Type">
        <select class="form-control" id="tags" type="text" ng-model="cap.categoryid" placeholder="Category Type" name="categoryid" required="" ng-init="loadcat()" ng-change="GetProduct(cap.categoryid,$index);GetSubCategory(cap.categoryid,cap.productname)">  
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="cat in CategoryArray" value="{{cat.Category_Id}}">{{cat.Category_Name}}</option>
                    </select>
      </td>

      <td data-title="'Product'" sortable="Product">
        <select class="form-control" type="text" name="productname" ng-model="cap.productname" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required ng-change="GetSubCategory(cap.categoryid,cap.productname)" />
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="pro in ProductsArray[$index]" value="{{pro.ProductId}}">{{pro.ProductlName}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td data-title="'Sub Category1'" sortable="Sub Category1">
        <select class="form-control" type="text" name="subcategoryid" ng-model="cap.subcategoryid" id="subcategoryid">
                     <option value="">Select</option>
                     <option ng-repeat="subcatid in subcatids" value="{{subcatid.Sub_category_Id}}">{{subcatid.Sub_Category_Name}} </option>
                    </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a ng-click="addFormField()" ng-if="data.length==$index+1" class='btn btn-default btn-xs' autofocus data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
          <a ng-click="remove_Row($index)" class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' autofocus data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I'am getting `CategoryArray` data using `ng-init="loadcat()"` on `ng-change="GetProduct(cap.categoryid)"` of category fetching dynamic data in `ProductsArray`. And I like also on `ng-change="GetSubCategory(cap.categoryid,cap.productname)"` of productname to fetch the dynamic data in `subcatids`

But the problem is while I'am adding one more row, again selecting category the `ProductsArray` changing for previous row also.

**Q:** How could I get `ProductsArray` on every selecting category in ng repeat for every iteration?

Comment: so you want `ProductsArray` to be different per row? Simply create an array instead. You can select the right index with `GetProduct(cap.categoryid, $index)` -> `$scope.ProductsArray[index] = data;` and display it with `ng-repeat="pro in ProductsArray[$index]"`

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey, yes sir. I want ProductsArray to be different per row. i tired as you given instructions. unable to fetching data into array

Comment: edit your question with the code that you tried, we are unable to test your example since you are using `$http` request, instead of pre-defined values

Comment: since it's an array now, you should initialise it in your controller first: `$scope.ProductsArray = [];` **then** you need to populate it with anything before you can add something to its index. E.g. `$scope.ProductsArray = Array($scope.data.length).fill([]);`

Comment: yes we need to init $scope.ProductsArray = []; Thanks you very much  @  Aleksey Solovey .it's working now